# Will a transistor always reduce the voltage?

Tags: power, transistor

I have an NPN transistor that's connected over a 12V adapter. I have tried using a potentiometer to change the resistance of the incomming current. Even if i take the resistance down to 0, I end up with at most 11 Volts when measuring over the magnet.

I have measure the energy without the transistor, in that case it's 12V. Is this expected behaviour of a transistor or is something wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Arduino and should be posted on EE.SE. There isn't even the word "Arduino" once in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is, as both V<sub>CE(sat)</sub> and the "Collector-Emitter Saturation Voltage vs Collector Current" chart in the datasheet tells you.

Comment: By context I'm assuming "yes it is expected behaviou"

Comment: 1V seems a bit high. But since we don't know the current through the electromagnet, or the transistor, or the base-resistor, it might well be true.

Comment: @Himmators the actual vales in datasheet depend on your specific transistor -which you didnt state in this question